# How to remove the first element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new in java script I want to remove the first element from array. any please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
You can use this method **Array.prototype.shift()**
It removes the first element from an array and returns that element.
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `shift()` method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.
>    — [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```
my_array.shift();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourarray.splice(0, 1);
```

Here first arg `0` represents the index of the item to be removed.
More info [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score -1):

You can use slice().

An example might be:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]; 
var fruitsWithoutFirst = fruits.slice(1);
```